# The equivalent of dragging in Excel but in an Access query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a rather large file, too big for Excel so I am stuck with Access and it has a format like this:

```
ID     Type    Amount
1234   A       500
       B       750
       C       589
5678   A       200
       F       9000
9101   H       44
```

My issue is that the ID field is only represented once during the grouping yet there can be multiple rows associated with it.  Is there a way using SQL to essentially drag down the ID field for all the blank values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the file is too big for Excel then, as mentioned, you'll need to break it into chunks.

In Excel you can fill the blanks with the ID above as follows:

- Select the column, or just the data (including blanks) in the column
- Choose the Home tab, Find & Select group, Go to Special (or Ctrl-G, click Special..)
- Select Blanks and press Ok; this will select all blank cells in the range
- Type = and press the Up arrow on the keyboard to select whichever cell is immediately above the active cell
- Press Ctrl-Enter to fill this same formula in all the empty cells
- Highlight the column again and Copy, right-click Paste-Special, Values.

It is nowhere near as easy to do this in Access. You would firstly need to create an artificial, number-sequence column (in Excel) to remember the original order. A quite complicated sequence of queries would then be needed. Do this entirely in Excel if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA no. Access can't deduce what you want the field values to be. If you have no knowledge of VBA-Access or even VBA I suggest you cut the file in smaller chunks and use Excel if that's possible. If the file would be even too large for that then you need to pick up VBA programming.

Comment: I just want to correct my post. In the case that none of this works, probably you'd be better with another language than VBA but it can do the job.